# JS w/ Kendo: Change label text on dropdown selection change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to change an Input label in my cshtml file by using my JS script, when any drop down selection is made.  I've followed the documentation - but I'm not getting the intended result.  There are no compile or runtime errors - and I have cut out anything that I didn't think was necessary for you all to see.  Please let me know if I've left something out.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="searchByInput" class="rptInputBxWidth" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Value" data-value-field="Key" data-bind="value:searchBys_Value, enabled:searchBys_Enabled, source:searchBys_Source " data-option-label="SELECT" data-auto-bind="false" data-value-primitive="true" />

<td id="entryFieldInputLabel" class="inputLabel" align="right">123456</td>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#searchByInput').change(searchByDropDownSelectionChange)
})

function searchByDropDownSelectionChange() {
  $('#entryFieldInputLabel').text('Changed')
}
```

I've removed the many table row tags, and the data source loads correctly as well.  What I expect to happen is that when the drop down `(#searchByInput)` is changed, the text on the label `(#entryFieldInputLabel)` is changed to "Changed"

Answer (score 0):

Use `html` selector instead of `text` (td has no text proprety ):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#searchByInput').change(searchByDropDownSelectionChange)
})

function searchByDropDownSelectionChange() {
  $('#entryFieldInputLabel').html('Changed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchByInput" class="rptInputBxWidth" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Value" data-value-field="Key" data-bind="value:searchBys_Value, enabled:searchBys_Enabled, source:searchBys_Source " data-option-label="SELECT" data-auto-bind="false" data-value-primitive="true" />
<table>
  <tr><td id="entryFieldInputLabel" class="inputLabel" align="right">1234</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It would be better if you use span inside your table `td`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#searchByInput').change(searchByDropDownSelectionChange)
})

function searchByDropDownSelectionChange() {
  $('#entryFieldInputLabel span').html('Changed')
}

/*
or simply
 $('#searchByInput').change(function(){
      $('#entryFieldInputLabel').html('Changed');
  })
  
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchByInput" class="rptInputBxWidth" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Value" data-value-field="Key" data-bind="value:searchBys_Value, enabled:searchBys_Enabled, source:searchBys_Source " data-option-label="SELECT" data-auto-bind="false" data-value-primitive="true" />
<table>
  <tr><td id="entryFieldInputLabel" class="inputLabel" align="right"><span>123</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I attempted both solutions, with and without the <span>, and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: if you are trying to select `td` element it has to be inside `table`> `tr`, your current html is not a valid html.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, as I mentioned in my original comment (and my response below) the element is in fact inside of both <table> and <tr>.  I apologize for leaving this out of the initial question specifically.

Comment: If it is not working that means you have another error, please check your console ... PS: `change` event happens if your element is no more focused.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `<table>` Markup so jQuery can select your `<td>` tag ID

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#searchByInput').change(searchByDropDownSelectionChange);

 function searchByDropDownSelectionChange() {
  $('#entryFieldInputLabel').text('Changed!');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="searchByInput" class="rptInputBxWidth" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Value" data-value-field="Key" data-bind="value:searchBys_Value, enabled:searchBys_Enabled, source:searchBys_Source " data-option-label="SELECT" data-auto-bind="false" data-value-primitive="true" />

<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="entryFieldInputLabel" class="inputLabel" align="right">123456</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Both the drop down list, and the input label exist inside of <table> ... they are in different tables, would that have any effect?

Comment: No, it will work. Your code is correct , you just have to respect the HTML tags structure.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved, and can be closed.  The solutions offered both reaffirmed that the issue was not in the code I provided.  After experimentation, the solution was found in the order in which the "change" call was made in the JS ready function.

This particular call needed to be made after the page specific HTML was loaded, but before the kendo data was bound by ID.